# Handling events when using youtube iframe and socket.io

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm creating an app where two users can watch a youtube video in real time using socket.io. In theory, all of the users will be also to use the video player controls, but an infinite loop occurs if one of the users press play/pause button multiple times in quick succession. How could I prevent this from happening?

Server code:

```
 socket.on("player status", playerStatus => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("status", playerStatus)
    })
```

Client-side code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('/');

    socketRef.current.on("status", status => {
        if (status === 1) {
            youtubePlayer.current.playVideo();
        } else {
            youtubePlayer.current.pauseVideo();
        }
    })
}, []);

function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
    if (e.data === 1 || e.data === 2) {
        socketRef.current.emit("player status", e.data)
    }
}
```